# can't seem to find the linker I'm looking for linking objects under python.h

Tags: c++, linker-errors, linker-flags

I have `python3.4` and have installed `python3-dev`( I have directory at `/usr/include/python3.4`). I also have `boost-python-dev` installed.

To compile my cpp file, I'm using

```
g++ python-binding/struct.cpp -I /usr/include/python3.4 -I python-binding/src -lboost_python -lpython3.4
```

but my compiler can't seem to find `-lpython3.4`

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.4
```

I've also tired with `-lpython3` `-lpython` `-Python3.4` but none works.

Comment: @Anthony Sottile thanks, I found out it was `-lpython3.4m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the particular linking flags by utilizing `pkg-config` -- on my machine the invocation is `pkg-config --libs python-3.4` (though my minimum version is 3.6 currently)

the output will look something like this:

```
$ pkg-config --libs python-3.6
-lpython3.6m
```